# "checkout" a folder and its history into a new repository

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detach subdirectory into separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository)

I guess what I'm asking is completely impossible... but it's worth to ask :)

I've got a repository where I saved both code and binary files (like PSDs). The folders  structure it's like this (hugely simplified):

- GIT-PROJECT

  - DESIGNS
  - CODE

What I'd like to do now is splitting DESIGNS and CODE... I will then move DESIGNS to Dropbox and instead carry-on saving CODE on github.

So... my question is can I start a new git repository with CODE as root and keep the commit history for that folder?

NOTE: one of the reasons why I wanna get rid of the DESIGNS folder is that I need to save space :) DESIGNS got huge during the time... and I would prefer not to upgrade my Github paid plan because of that.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I searched before... but with no luck. This sure looks like what I'm after... as Charles suggested. I'll have a look, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

git filter-branch does the trick of keeping the history and dropping everything else.

```
$ git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter CODE
```

Beware this is destructive.  Later you might want to do:

```
$ git reflog expire --expire=now
$ git gc --prune=now
```

You will see a considerable reduction of the repository size, only having the history of CODE and removing all those unreachable objects.

Comment: `--aggressive` is probably not a good idea, and `gc` includes `prune`. You probably meant `git reflog expire --expire=now` followed by `git gc --prune=now`.

Comment: reflog expire it is better.  --aggressive still can be necessary, but it might depend on a specific case.  I fixed to make it less dangerous. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just commit a change that removes the `DESIGNS` and moves the `CODE` up to the top level? This way history will be completely and accurately preserved.

E.g. (from `GIT-PROJECT`)

```
git rm -r DESIGNS # assumes you've saved DESIGNS somewhere
git mv 'CODE/*' .

git commit -m "Removed DESIGNS, moved code to the top level"
```

If you really want to expunge `DESIGNS` from the history of the repository and pretend that the code was always at the top level you can use [`git filter-branch`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-filter-branch.html) with the `--tree-filter` or `--subdirectory-filter` to rewrite history, although this is a more involved change.

Comment: Sorry... I forgot to mention that I'm using github and I'd like to remove DESIGNS to save space. Just removing the folder and then commit the change, wouldn't make any difference I guess.